# problem in code, grabs link but doesnt ask for login

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Keep getting this error on my pc but the program runs fine on my buddy's PC. Does anyone know why? I am not that knowledgeable but the code was written by a friend and he can't figure out a fix. Btw it will open a chrome browser but not ask for login inputs in terminal instead will return the error found below. Thanks for the help in advance.
**CODE**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
from time import sleep

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', service = s, options=chrome_options)

delay=1
def login():
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    os.system('cls')
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]'))).click()
    sleep(1)
    username = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='username')
    user = input("Enter your username: ")
    username.send_keys(user)
    password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='password')
    passwd = input("Enter your password: ")
    password.send_keys(passwd)
    password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    sleep(5)
    print('Logged in')
    return driver
login()
def storieslike():
    with open("followers.txt", "r+", encoding="utf8") as f:
        for row in f:
            driver.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/stories/{row}/')
            sleep(4)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/main/div/div/article/div[1]')))
                print("profile private. skipping...")
            except:
                try:
                    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/button'))).click()
                    sleep(1)
                    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/section/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/span/button'))).click()
                    print("Liked story of " + row)
                except:
                    print('Failed to Like story.')
storieslike()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/natha/Desktop/Story Liker/main/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    login()
  File "c:/Users/natha/Desktop/Story Liker/main/main.py", line 22, in login
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]'))).click()        
  File "C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x011F6463+2188387]
        Ordinal0 [0x0118E461+1762401]
        Ordinal0 [0x010A3D78+802168]
        Ordinal0 [0x010D1880+989312]
        Ordinal0 [0x010D1B1B+989979]
        Ordinal0 [0x010FE912+1173778]
        Ordinal0 [0x010EC824+1099812]
        Ordinal0 [0x010FCC22+1166370]
        Ordinal0 [0x010EC5F6+1099254]
        Ordinal0 [0x010C6BE0+945120]
        Ordinal0 [0x010C7AD6+948950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x014971F2+2712546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0148886D+2652765]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0128002A+520730]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0127EE06+516086]
        Ordinal0 [0x0119468B+1787531]
        Ordinal0 [0x01198E88+1805960]
        Ordinal0 [0x01198F75+1806197]
        Ordinal0 [0x011A1DF1+1842673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76D2FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77717A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77717A6E+238]
```

Comment: Check if there is something that blocks the page, for example cookies panel.

Comment: I will try to see if this helps

Answer (score 0):

The error is on wait i.e `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]'))).click()`

The error is associated with element indicated by xpath `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]` not being present on the page

Although remove the click on the element i.e `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]'))).click()` **the script runs fine**
without any error and can enter login credentials

**Note:-** Check for you in case while script runs if you encounter the element    indicated i.e  `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]` on screen  can perform the click on element by passing the locator for the element or the relative xpath

Your solution would look like

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe', service = s, options=chrome_options)
delay=1
def login():
  driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
  os.system('cls')
  time.sleep(1)
  username = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='username')
  user = input("Enter your username: ")
  username.send_keys(user)
  password = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='password')
  passwd = input("Enter your password: ")
  password.send_keys(passwd)
  password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(5)
  print('Logged in')
  return driver
login()
```

Comment: Okso this worked but now i have an issue in the rest of the code, the program will open but fails to like Instagram stories because the code was removed. The code is meant to click a button but when removed the function doesn't inst able to complete tasks, if left in it will not even ask for login. I tried this but I get the same original error. delay=1
def login():
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
    os.system('cls')
    meow = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]')))
    meow.click()

Comment: Hi @nathan can you move the part where you perform wait   i.e `meow=WebdriverWait`  and `meow.click` after login is completed i.e after printing `logged in` and you are on the page where the button is present. We need to ensure the element we are trying to click is present in the page before we perform click action. In the original one we are trying to click on the login page itself where it's not present since we haven't logged in

Comment: sleep(5)
    print('Logged in')
    meow = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/div/button[2]')))
    meow.click()
    return driver
login()

Comment: I moved it here but it did not work

Comment: File "C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I added the rest of the code in the original post. @darshan-shah

Comment: Can you provide one of the link you use i e from followers.txt `Instagram/stories/row`

Comment: make this into a txt.
shinearmor_yt
kevin______martz
noah_nh24
j4sxn.ybn_u
2highbree
z34.breerosales
breerosales
george.letha.7
rama_krisha2021
rajeshmandal923
oj_livermore
rodrigueshamurabi
skimmerdubois
thats_frostbite
spikedperformance
kidwyatas
cateye_no_cats
whatthefisupdennys
ap_o8
lyssa_pamela
insta.cars.la
pitaz_11
ana_beatriz.fenix
jake._stern
yung_gee_cruz
chronic_egolifter
brightslide_drift
zvrags
socal_smoke_show
martin_betsy05
s.amanthhaaa
shot.bydanipdx
555.zack
__erniecalderon
3runo.jr
therons197
aylinncelis
babya0724
that3vgirl
dianetttt_

Comment: Update. I have fixed the entire code.